# resolvconf got uninstalled and can't install it again

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg, resolvconf

So when I do:

```
sudo apt-get install *Package*
```

It says:

```
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resolvconf
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to see what the problem is I type:

```
sudo resolvconf
```

It says:

```
Command 'resolvconf' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install openresolv  # version 3.10.0-1, or
sudo apt install resolvconf  # version 1.82
```

Then when I try to install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

It gives me the same apt-get error as before. I have tried installing the deb package but it says:

```
Unable to install resolvconf:
Error while installing package: new resolvconf package post-
removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

What can I do to fix this. I can provide any extra information you need. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 lts.

Comment: You need to fix errors from prior comments before trying new commands. Have you tried `sudo apt -f install` or other --fix-broken options?  (without package so it corrects existing issues rather than compounding the problem)

Comment: hanks this worked! Could you please make a answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix errors from prior commands before trying new commands.

First and easiest is

`sudo apt -f install`

or other --fix-broken options? It's issued without package so it corrects existing issues rather than compounding the problem.

From `[man apt-get`][1](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/apt-get.8.html)

> ```
>    -f, --fix-broken
>        Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when
>        used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely
>        solution. If packages are specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The
>        option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not
>        allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's
>        dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which
>        usually means using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages). Use of
>        this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations. Configuration
>        Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
> ```